# Update to Box and Jenkins Air Passenger data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, references, teaching

A textbook example of a time series is the Box and Jenkins Air Passenger data. In R you can get it with the command `data(AirPassengers)`. It has the number of international airline passengers each month from 1949 till 1960.

> Is there anywhere to download the true number of international airline passengers in 1961?

I want that data so my students can compare several different forecasts to see which was closest in reality. I feel like this data set would be useful to essentially everyone who teaches forecasting.

Comment: How in god's name was this question closed in 56 seconds? I have to say, I'm not really loving Cross Validated. Nowhere near as friendly as Math Overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry that this happened. This doesn't usually happen. If you'd like, you can create a post on https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/ asking for clarification.